# Getting error near 'SET' keyword in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I created a stored procedure but I get error near 'SET' keyword:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure []usp_chkuseridpwd], Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.
>   incorrect syntax near 'set', expecting variable.

My code:

```
alter procedure [usp_chkuseridpwd]
as
begin
    declare 
        /*variable declaration */
        @sql as varchar(max),
        @tblname varchar(max),
        @user_name varchar(max),
        @user_password varchar(max),
        @count int,
        @passwd as varchar(max),

    set @sql = 'select COUNT(*) from user_master where USER_NAME like '+@user_name+' and pasword like '+@user_password+''
    exec(@sql)
end
```

Comment: Pay attention to the syntax. The last row of the `DECLARE`, `@passwd as varchar(max),`, should not terminate with a comma.

Comment: Remove the extra comma at the end of the DECLARE .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be:

```
alter procedure [usp_chkuseridpwd]
as
begin
    declare 
        /*variable declaration */
        @sql as varchar(max),
        @tblname varchar(max),
        @user_name varchar(max),
        @user_password varchar(max),
        @count int,
        @passwd as varchar(max)

    set @sql = 'select COUNT(*) from user_master where USER_NAME like '+@user_name+' and pasword like '+@user_password+''
    exec(@sql)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have one extra comma in the `@passwd as varchar(max),`

Removing the comma will solve your problem.

**UPDATE:**

This is not relevant to the error.

But you may need to include `'%'` when you are using with `LIKE` operator to get more relevant results. With out wildcard `'%'` you need to pass the exact string to get result. In case if you are know the partial string of the user name and want to fetch all the records, you need this `'%'`

So the stored procedure will be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [usp_chkuseridpwd]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        /*variable declaration */
        @sql as varchar(max),
        @tblname varchar(max),
        @user_name varchar(max),
        @user_password varchar(max),
        @count int,
        @passwd as varchar(max) -- removing the comma 

    -- Added % for the LIKE operator
    SET @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_master WHERE USER_NAME LIKE %' + @user_name + '% AND pasword LIKE %' + @user_password + '%'
    EXEC(@sql)
END
```